# Set default value for parameter in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

I am creating a report in pentaho report designer and need some help setting default values for a parameter that I've created.

One of the parameters labeled date fetches data from the date column of a table. While I am able to view all the dates in the drop down list, I am unable to find a way in which I can set the default value of this drop down to all (meaning all the dates together).

Is there a way in which I can set the 'all' value as default?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get the values for the filter from a JDBC connection in PRD, you can write a query like this. (I have used Postgresql).
This will load `'All'` as the first values in the drop down and other distinct date values from your table. (Do the casting properly)

```
SELECT 1 AS sort,'All' AS date
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT 2 AS sort,

     tablename.datecolumn::date AS date
FROM
   tablename

ORDER BY sort
```

Then in your parameter that is shown to the user to select the date, enter `All` in `Default Value` field and select the query that we have written. 
Next assuming that you use a KTR to retrieve data to your report, you can include the following query in a 'Table input' step,

```
(tablename.datecolumn IN (SELECT CASE WHEN('${date}' = 'All' OR '${date}' IS NULL) THEN tablename.datecolumn ELSE '${date}'  END))
```

Hope this will help. If you have any further issues please comment below. Because this has worked perfectly for me.